# An entity annotated with @Inheritance cannot use @AttributeOverride or @AttributeOverrides:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've a MapperSuperclass called BaseTable:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseTable {

    @Column(
        length = 100
    )
    private String myColumn;

    ....

}
```

and an entity that extends from BaseTable called Table

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
    dynamicUpdate = true
)
@Inheritance(
    strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE
)
public class Table extends BaseTable {

    ....

}
```

Now I want to extend `Table` and add a unique constraint to column `myColumn`. I tried attribute override like below:

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name = "myColumn", column = @Column(name = "my_column", unique = true))
public class MyTable extends Table {

    .....

}
```

But it is giving me the following errror:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: An entity annotated with @Inheritance cannot use @AttributeOverride or @AttributeOverrides: com.example.demo.MyTable
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:404) [spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.loadParentContext(ContextLoader.java:563) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:322) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar:2.0.19.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar:2.0.19.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar:2.0.19.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar:2.0.19.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar:2.0.19.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250) [undertow-servlet-2.0.19.Final.jar:2.0.19.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_222]
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_222]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
```

Say that I'm not allowed to modify BaseTable and Table as they come from added libraries, How can I add a unique constraint to the column `myColumn`?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK 5.3.7.final

Comment: Doesn't `@UniqueConstraint` on `Table` work? Why do you feel you need `@AttributeOverride`?

Comment: @crizzis I'm not allowed to modify `BaseTable` and `Table` as they come from added libraries

Comment: What about `@UniqueConstraint` on `MyTable`? As a side note, you'd be better off switching to some DB schema management tool like Flyway or Liquibase. Using Hibernate for schema generation is not exactly a recommended practice for a production setting

Answer (score 0):

You can only use @AttributeOverride to an entity that extends a mapped superclass.
To put unique constraint on entity use @UniqueConstraint as crizzis mentioned.
Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"my_column"})
        })
public class MyTable { .. }
```